# How to force new users to only see and use the classic experience?

Tags: lightning, salesforce-classic

I want newly invited users to only see the classic experience, and not the Lightning Experience.

Comment: unclear but the answer has 5 upvotes?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As the [Set Up Users for Lightning Experience](https://releasenotes.docs.salesforce.com/en-us/winter16/release-notes/lex_enable_users.htm) documentation explains there is a "Lightning Experience User" permission that you can ensure is unchecked on the profiles (and permission sets) you choose for the newly invited users.